# How to align child components horizontally to occupy a certain percentage of the container's width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, rendering

I have three different React components in the following format:

```
<Container className={"parent"}>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <Tabs className={"childOne"}/>
    <Info className={"childTwo"}/>
</Container>
```

Each of the above child components render other child components and native html tags like `<div>`s and `<span>`s.

This is how I want the components to render on the browser:

[image: Component layout]

I have tried achieving this using CSS `flex-box`. However, the child components only take up the width of their content and I am not able to proportion their widths into 66% and 33% of the container respectively (with some gap in between). This is the CSS I tried:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.childOne {
  flex-basis: 70%;
}

.childTwo {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
```

I also tried `display: inline-block;` and `float:left` on each of the child components but this did not even align the children horizontally.

Could someone please show me how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: you should use bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap isn't an option for me - I need to use some custom design library.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to use flexbox. Here you have an example. You can add as many columns as you want.

Code based on Bootstrap 5.

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex:1 0 100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.row > *{
  flex-shrink:0;
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
.col-4{
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width:33.333333%;
}
.col-8{
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width:66.666667%;
}
/*DEMO*/*{box-sizing:border-box}.col-4,.col-8{padding:1.5rem;border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">A</div>
  <div class="col-4">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to actually use bootstrap for this?

Comment: You don't need to use bootstrap. This is a standard flexbox :)

Comment: This is the output I am getting with your solution: https://imgur.com/Wq1cYUR. Anything I can change?

Comment: Maybe you have a conflict with other CSS? What about container?

Comment: The Container is actually a simple <div>. No custom CSS there.

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle and show your code? https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You're using `flex-basis: 50%` on both which will be equal and not as you expected it.
Maybe make `childOne` flex-basis of 70%?

You can also make `flex: 2` on childOne and `flex: 1` on child two.

Here is a code example: https://codepen.io/jsmohamed/pen/XWXaMbp

Comment: apologies, that was an error while posting the question. I did indeed try with 70% and 30%. The question has been corrected

Comment: This is the output I am getting with your solution (same as the other answer's): https://imgur.com/Wq1cYUR